# Conditionally format entire spreadsheet based on partial text in first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have been manually highlighting all these rows and cells.  Is there any way for conditional formatting to do this for me?

They are always based on partial text that repeats in column A (for example:  I want every row highlighted that has the word `TASSOS` in column A).  then I want ONLY the +/- numbers in that row in column B to be red if negative and blue if positive.

I spend hours "coloring" these reports every month.

```
OLIVES RIPE MARIO           8,868   -12 -1,251
OLIVES SPANISH MARIO        8,990     0     16
OLIVES RIPE BLACK PEARL     3,093   115  1,657
OLIVES RIPE LINDSAY           862     5     41
OLIVES SPANISH MEZZETTA     3,345    -8   -293
OLIVES RIPE MEZZETTA          906    -8    -80
OLIVES SPANISH TASSOS         476    21     84
OLIVES SPANISH GREEN PEARL    161     1      2
OLIVES RIPE TASSOS            344   -13    -53
OLIVES RIPE HOMESTYLE PEARL   132   -18    -29
OLIVES SPANISH BOSCOLI        622    59    231
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try Conditional Formatting formula rules as below:

select ColumnsA:Z (or to suit "entire" row):

```
 =FIND("TASSOS",$A1)
```

and choose your highlighting. Select ColumnB:

```
=AND(FIND("TASSOS",$A1),B1>0)
```

with blue font. Repeat for red font with:

```
=AND(FIND("TASSOS",$A1),B1<0)
```